# What exactly is Software Development for IoT?

Tags: self-improvement, iot

I am looking forward to understanding what **software development for IoT** is all about.

What exactly is **software engineering for IoT** all about?

How different is it from the traditional software development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest difference is **hardware constraints.**  A thermostat hanging on your wall is clearly going to have less processing power and memory space than your desktop computer.  That will clearly affect the way you program it.

If you want to explore IoT software development yourself, just buy an [Arduino starter kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D8KOZF4) and play around with lighting up LED's or running small motors.

Comment: As an aside, Robert ... "having been in this business for *(koff, koff)* a long time now," I've been amused at how we've come full circle on many things.  Long ago, we were playing around with circuit boards – then with 8080's on them or something even less.  And now, here we are again: playing around with circuit boards! **:-D**

Comment: I agree. It's bog-standard "embedded development", with an ethernet or WiFi facility added (rather than say RS485).

Comment: I’ve been listening to IoT hype for what seems like forever and it still just seems like embedded systems that have an IP address. Am I missing something?

Comment: @candied_orange: that's most of it, except where the true customer is an advertising company, along with a complete lack of security considerations.

Comment: If you want something that can live on a battery for a good while look into low power pic32 development boards.